# Counting no. of rings occured in a remote phone

Tags: c#, serial-port, at-command

I have created a C# program that can dial a phone. Now what I have to do is count the number of rings occuring in the remote phone device.

My C# program uses the command  ***ATDT [phoneno]*** to dial the number. If remote phone rings more than 5 times, I have to perform some other activites.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Is the remote device a modem connected to your computer or is there some other signal you need to check for the ring?  Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. it's actually an IVR system to which I am trying to connect with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot achieve that over a standar modem and serial port.  The best you can do is have a timeout.  Whilst ringing, the modem just looks out for the carrier signal before initiating any communications.  It doesn't count rings.

If you absolutely must do that, it would involve taking the audio from the modem and processing it to get the ring count (not trivial as depending on the telephone network etc, ringing varies considerably and can be confused with hold tones).

Comment: This isn't true.  Most modems will report a `RING`.  If you open the serial port and watch the incomming string you will see `RING` (or something similar when the line is ringing.  You should be able to count these messages within a particular time frame.

Comment: That is not the "most" rule.  Most (cheap) modems do not support this.  I think the last one I saw that did this was a 28k hayes optima.

Comment: Have you tried?  It's pretty standard practice for fax and data modem services to listen for RING

Comment: Yeah I tried it on a couple of cheap V90 56k modems back in the early '00s and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know you can't count the real number of rings. Just think about a handy that doesn't ring but plays a song. So all you can do is running a timer and hang up after the timeout is reached (e.g. 20 seconds).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the modem you should be able to get a ring notification.  Open the serial port for input and watch for a word such as `RING` while the line is called.  You should be able to start a counter of some sort and watch the line status.  You may need to look at the advanced AT commands for your device to ensure that it is configured to report these notifications.

- [Some MODEM `AT` commands](http://michaelgellis.tripod.com/modem.html)

It looks like you might want to look at registers `S0` and `S1`.